# Как правильно оформить это предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь, двоеточие

***Он мечтал, что она скажет (?) "Д/да, хочу!", и их жизнь изменится к лучшему.***

Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку знаков препинания и написание заглавной или строчной буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Он мечтал, что она скажет: **"Да, хочу!"** — и их жизнь изменится к лучшему.*

**Пояснение**

1. **Тире**, а не запятая ставится при восклицательной прямой речи. Оформление прямой речи по обычным правилам (двоеточие, кавычки, прописная буква).
2. **[У Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159):** : И только когда он шептал: **«Мама! Мама!»** — ему становилось как будто легче (Ч.) — **тире** после **восклицательного** знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь.
3. **Сравнить:**

*И только когда он шептал **эти слова**, ему становилось как будто легче.* СПП без прямой речи, ставится **запятая**.

*И только когда он шептал: **«Мама, мама»**,  ему становилось как будто легче.* При наличии прямой речи без восклицательного знака **запятая** сохраняется.